# flutter build web - Only showing blank page

Tags: flutter, web, deployment, flutter-web

Strangely, I am unable to deploy flutter apps via Flutter web since some days.
I have not problem running and debugging the Flutter app in a chrome browser via Android studio but once I try

> flutter build web

the generated index.html file unter /build/web/ will show a blank page with these errrors:
[Chrome error messages image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjRbt.png)

I started a completely new project so the error will not be due to my bad code writing :P

Can somebody help?

Comment: How are you deploying it?

Comment: Did you check the line 54 of the html? What does it say?

Comment: it registers a serviceWorker with 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion while serviceWorkerVersion initialized as 293056707. Where can I configure the serviceWorker apart from the index.html (haven't changed anything from a blank Flutter project) and what version can I set? When removing the serviceWorker I still have the main.dart.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND - Thx in advance :)

Comment: I like to deploy ist with Github pages so basically I want a local index.html-file that directly runs the app

Comment: update: I ran 'flutter clean' and 'flutter pub get' then 'flutter build web'. Now at least sometimes when opening from Android Studio the index.html in /build/web/ can be opened. But when every other time one needs to enter a unsername and a password to open the website... Also, when opening the index.html locally from the explorer/finder, the same errors occur just as before...

Answer (score 5):

just change to `<base href="./">` in `index.html` after you build the web.

Answer (score 5):

Try remove `.dart-tool` folder in your `project folder` and rebuild your projcet.

I had the same error and changing index.html not worked. I solved it by removing .dart-tool folder in your project folder. After removing it, IDE shows some errors but flutter build web works fine.
Here is the origin link. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61464#issuecomment-924577391

Answer (score 1):

just Clear browsing data in privacy and security
if not see any  error in the console

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but it seems to perpetuate (I also crashed into it). So here is what helped me to solve the problem:

The [doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/url-strategies) says:

```
Update the <base href="/"> tag in web/index.html to the path where your app is hosted.
```

In my case, it was  htdocs/app, so base href become `<base href="/app">`, which fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

While using `flutter build web` if it shows a blank page then it is because of the base url missing in index.html .
You can Use

`flutter build web --release --web-renderer html --base-href ./`

Try building web folder again using this code.

Comment: For Flutter version 3.13.6, this results in an error: "base-href should start and end with /".

Answer (score 0):

## Context

My Flutter web on mobile browsers (not on computers or emulator's browser) starts up the splash screen, following by redirecting to a new route (including [usePathUrlStrategy](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation/url-strategies), until here works well.

But then no matter the route and screen widget, it only shows a blank page.

## Problem

Debugging the web app running on my Android Chrome via my computer's Chrome developer console via USB `chrome://inspect/#devices` said:

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getSupportedModes on channel flutter_display_mode)
```

## Solution

Delete code associated to that library [flutter_displaymode](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_displaymode) (refresh rate of the phone screen), else use the conditional import method to not import the library incompatible with web.

Here is an example of unrelated to `flutter_displaymode`, nonetheless, it could help you

```dart
// The file of your widget where you use the functionality runned only for web.

import 'logic/common/platform_specific.dart' if (dart.library.html) 'logic/common/platform_specific_web.dart';

...

PlatformSpecificImpl.setPageTitle(title);
```

```dart
// File `platform_specific_web.dart`. On web, it setups up the web page.
 
import 'dart:html' as html;

import 'platform_specific_abstract.dart';

class PlatformSpecificImpl implements PlatformSpecific {
  static void setPageTitle(String title) {
    html.document.title = title;
  }
}
```

```dart
// File `platform_specific.dart`. On desktop and mobile, it does nothing.

import 'platform_specific_abstract.dart';

class PlatformSpecificImpl implements PlatformSpecific {
  static void setPageTitle(String title) {}
}
```

```dart
// File `platform_specific_abstract.dart`

abstract class PlatformSpecific {
  static void setPageTitle(String title) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If running in a bash-like terminal, run the following to build and tweak the base href in a single command line. You can also append an scp command to automatically copy the results to your web server.

```
flutter build web && sed -i '/<base href/s/\//.\//' build/web/index.html
```